# @nuxtjs/color-mode interrupts plugin to work normally

Tags: typescript, scroll, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt-plugin

I have project build using Nuxt3(typescript, tailwindcss, nuxtjs/color-mode) and I use smooth-scroll.js as plugin to reduce speed of scrolling.

But that plugin not working properly because of @nuxtjs/color-mode

When I place theme color-mode function to app.vue it works perfect, but when I turn it into component and use it in Navbar.vue and use this Navbar.vue in app.vue color-mode reduces scroll speed so much that you can barely scroll the page.

What might be the solution in order to work smooth-scroll plugin properly.

Site address: infocript.netlify.app

I have project build using Nuxt3(typescript, tailwindcss, nuxtjs/color-mode) and I use smooth-scroll.js as plugin to reduce speed of scrolling.

But that plugin not working properly because of @nuxtjs/color-mode

When I place theme color-mode function to app.vue it works perfect, but when I turn it into component and use it in Navbar.vue and use this Navbar.vue in app.vue color-mode reduces scroll speed so much that you can barely scroll the page.

What might be the solution in order to work smooth-scroll plugin properly.

Site address: infocript.netlify.app